# Moving Agents from Storage to Storage in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, logistics

I'd like to move agents (pallets) from storage to storage in Anylogic. The idea is to move pallet from storage A to B in Anylogic, but the STORE block demands that you pick up those agents from something else other than a storage itself.
The problem starts from the red arrow below towards the rest of the process flow.
The red circle is where I'm focusing and stuck at.

[Process Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izeh4.png)

[Retrieve block parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpikr.png)

[Store block parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKKfX.png)

So far, the AGVs pick up from storage, drop it on the ground and go to the next pick up (instead of completing the mission by storing in the next storage)

I have tried the solution found in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135072/in-anylogic-is-it-possible-to-send-an-agent-from-one-storage-to-another-directl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135072/in-anylogic-is-it-possible-to-send-an-agent-from-one-storage-to-another-direct) but without success.
I couldn't implement what is suggested there and I couldn't comment cause of my low rank here.
Although I choose the destination as agent coordinates, I can't find the suggested functions "agent.transporter=unit;" and "agent.transporter.equals(unit);"

[Retrieve details 'on seize' function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfVGR.png)

[Store details 'on seize' function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COO9M.png)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i gave the answer on that link and i would give the same answer to you.. 
agent.transporter is not a function, your agent needs a variable of type Transporter to save the transporter information.. you need to explain why that solution doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Anylogic, is it possible to send an agent from one storage to another directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135072/in-anylogic-is-it-possible-to-send-an-agent-from-one-storage-to-another-directl)